# How to use Rank() or ROW_NUMBER() mysql 8.0 + function in subquery value?

Tags: rank, row-number, mysql-8.0

Suppose I wank to rank user based on votes, and the votes are counting in a select subquery. So how to use `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` Mysql 8.0 + function with that subquery value.

Here is a working example where I used `RANK()` function order by `Select NULL` to accomplish Order BY votes

```sql
select *, (Rank() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as ranks, 
(select sum(votes)+person.votes from `category_model`) as `votes` 
from `person` order by `votes` desc
```

Instead of above Can I use `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`function with subquery value ??
like:

```sql
select *, (Rank() OVER(ORDER BY `votes`)) as ranks, 
(select sum(votes)+person.votes from `category_model`) as `votes` 
from `person`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move query to the JOIN and then use it. In your case at the time RANK is calculated you don't have votes yet. When you move it to the join it is joined first and you have the value already.

```
select *, (Rank() OVER(ORDER BY ORDER BY `votes`.`votes`+person.votes)) as ranks
from `person` 
CROSS JOIN (select sum(votes) from `category_model`) as `votes` 
order by `votes` desc
```